# Filtering by folder or authoritative maps when using gis.content.search

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-python-api

I use the code in Python

`for item in gis.content.search(query="owner:MyUsername", item_type='Feature Service')`

to go over the feature classes uploaded on my organization's AGOL page. I want to filter out layers that are

- Not View Layer
- Authoritative
- Are in a specific folder

Yet I had no success. I tried things such as

`folder='MyFolder, status=authoritative`

and I fail. Any solutions or workarounds on how to filter for these are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

May be you cannot combine all the filters in one search, I think this is the list of [fields](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/users-groups-and-items/search-reference.htm#) you can fine tune with?

You might need to do a bit of creative searching, you can filter items by folder [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.gis.toc.html#item) then test each items `content_status` for example?

Answer (score 0):

The code for Authoritative is: query="contentstatus:org_authoritative"

Did you get this to work?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our Focused question/Best answer model operates. Please edit your Answer to be more expansive (e.g., cite the documentation) and avoid asking a question (this is no it a discussion forum).